# SSH Broken Pipe on a specific network

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, osx-yosemite, openssh

I have an annoying problem with ssh connection. I get "Write failed: Broken pipe" error in 1-2 minutes.

I connect to various servers via ssh and never had this problem before. Until I moved to a new apartment and had new internet provider (o2/Germany)

I can still connect to servers without any problems if I am on another network.
But at home I get this error all the time.

Here what I have tried;

- I run a script with an infinite loop to keep the communication active -> still broken pipe
- I added the lines below in ~/.ssh/config and /etc/ssh_config -> still broken pipe

  ```
  Host *
      ServerAliveInterval 120
      TCPKeepAlive no
  ```
- I asked my network provider, they said this problem is not caused by their side and they don't have support this kind of problems

Please, Help
Cheers,
Eda

*I am using Mac OSX Yosemite (version 10.10.5)*

*ssh version: OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011*

Comment: If you tried something like `count=1; while ((1)); do echo $count; sleep 6; count=$((count+1)); done` then something firewall alike is destroying your connection and it **is** your ISPs fault.  One possible solution is to use login with a private key and something like `gnu screen`.   Add `screen -R` to `.bashrc` on the server side and a `while` loop that reconnects ssh on the client side.  **That is a horrid and dirty solution but it works**

Answer (score 0):

When we use the 'ssh' key broken pipe issue occurs. so I have a solution for this.
Run this command

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

on terminal than in a nano file after add two line

```
host *
ServerAliveInterval 60
 ServerAliveCountMax 1200
```

then save file and run on terminal